# Can't understand models and views in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

**1.What is verbose_name and verbose_name_plural in models.py ? 
How do they work here ?
2. why we added if category_slug: in views.py**

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:list_of_post_by_category', args =[self.slug])

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404
from .models import Post ,Category

def list_of_post_by_category(request,category_slug ):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    post = Post.objects.filter(status = 'published')
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404( Category, slug = category_slug)
        post = post.filter(category = category)

    return render(request , 'blog/category/list_of_post_by_category.html', {'categories': categories, 'post': post, 'category': category})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verbose name is human readable name. Suppose your model name is DistrictList. You will see 'District Lists' in django admin. 
If your field name is 'first_name' , django will convert it to 'First Name'

> **If the verbose name isn’t given, Django will automatically create
>   it using the field’s attribute name, converting underscores to
>   spaces**

if you want to customize it , i.e. you want to see 'List of sites' for the variable 'sites' use:

```
sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name="list of sites")
```

verbose name plural is plural of your name.

As, slug  is not required field, sometime's user's may not fill up this field. For this checking is applied.